# Code is correct, but I'm still getting syntax error message

Tags: mysql, create-table

I am trying to create a table in MySQL called Staff, however I get the error 1064 (42000) message.

I have checked line by line and character by character, but neither I nor my instructor have been able to identify any syntax error.

If I remove the Salary and Rank attributes I don't get an error, however they must be included in the table.

I have read several other questions relating to error 1064 but they have not been useful for me. I am also very new to MySQL as well. Thank you for your time.

Here is the code:

```
drop table if exists Staff;

create table Staff
    (Employee_ID    varchar(4),
     Employee_Name  varchar(10),
     Salary     numeric(7,0),
     Rank       varchar(8),
     primary key (Employee_ID)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

The exact error message is:
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Rank        varchar(8)
primary key (Employee_ID)
) ENGINE = INNODB' at line 5

Comment: The error message is quite precise.

Comment: If you're getting syntax errors the code is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

rank is a reserved word (as of MySQL 8.0...) Use backticks for it, or rename it.

```
drop table if exists Staff;

create table Staff
    (Employee_ID    varchar(4),
     Employee_Name  varchar(10),
     Salary     numeric(7,0),
     `Rank`       varchar(8),
     primary key (Employee_ID)
    ) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 1):

Rank is a reserved word.
Either rename it or quote it.